# Surface area and volume for Minkowski sum

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ two convex bodies in the euclideand space $\mathbb{E}^3$ (of dimesion 3):

Let's denote the $V$ as the volume and $S$ the surface area

I am looking for two thing(with reference):

1-The expression of the volume and the surface area of $K_1+K_2$
$$V(K_1+K_2) \quad \mbox{ and} \quad  S(K_1+K_2)$$

2-the geometrical meaning of each terms in $V(K_1+K_2) \quad \mbox{ and} \quad  S(K_1+K_2)$

For example, if $K_2$ is the euclidean unit ball $B$, by Steiner polynomial for the volume, we have
$$V(K_1+B)=V(K_1)+S(K_1)+M+V(B)$$
$M $ here is the total mean curvature of $K_1$,the others terms are clear (surface area and volume )

in dimension 2, Minkowski sums act linearly on the perimeter: the perimeter of the sum equals the sum of perimeters (which is clearly not the case one dimension 3)

Comment: An explicit formula is rather elaborate and usually not very enlightening, Are you perhaps trying to prove something using this formula? Usually, there is a simpler approach available to prove that something, depending on what it is.

Comment: @Deane . I am looking to understand this thing in dimension 3. In dimension 2 I know this notion very well but I did not find the explicit formula in dimension 3. for the volume there exists the general expression with the quermassintergal. but it's hard to understand

Comment: I agree the formulas for quermassintegrals are hard to understand directly. You eventually understand them better by learning their properties and working with them.

Comment: thank you @Deane for your comment. is there any place where can I find the Steiner polynomial for the surface area?  because I am totally lost in Rolf Schneider book's

Comment: Try this: http://webbuild.knu.ac.kr/~yjsuh/proceedings/14th/%5B14th%20proceeding%5D%2002.%20G.Zhang.pdf

Comment: For smooth bodies, the formulas here, in terms of symmetric functions of the principal curvatures, are simplest I know of. http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yongwei/folder/AW_ICCM2018.pdf

Comment: Thank's @Deane for this reference. so the surface area is $ W_1(K) $ ;)