# Volume of sum of a cube and a sphere

Tags: 3d, volume

Let $$C=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:|x|\leq1, |y|\leq 1, |z|\leq 1\}$$ be a cube  and $$S=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$$ be a sphere. Let us define $$C+S=\{c+s:c\in C, s\in S\}.$$Find the volume of $C+S$.

The main requirement is to determine the limits of $x, y$ and $z$ for the set $C+S$. After evaluating them, I get $$-2\leq x\leq 2$$ $$-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ $$-1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\leq z\leq 1+\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}.$$ This means the volume of $C+S$ is $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dz\, dy\, dx.$$
Is this the correct approach? Please help. Also, if this is the correct approach, then how to evaluate the integral $$ 2\int_{-2}^2\int_{-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} dy\, dx.$$

Comment: The problem you are solving is generally not so trivial. FYI, the set C+S that you defined is referred to as "Minkowski Sum" of C and S. In the literature, there are lots of sources about it, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4177370/surface-area-and-volume-for-minkowski-sum.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, for simple geometric sets, like in this case you can easily visualise how C+S looks like. You just need to "put" the centre of the sphere upon each vertex of the cube and get the convex hull of it.  It is a well-known topic of "Computational Geometry". So, you can get the area easily.

Comment: Look at it geometrically. For the analogous question of square and disk in the plane the set $C+S$ is a bigger "square with circular corners". You can compute its area quite easily by moving the pieces or just bit by bit. Then do the same in R^3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Intuitively $C+S$ consists of

- Eight eighth-spheres of radius $1$ (purple), with total volume $\frac43\pi$
- $12$ quarter-cylinders of height $2$ and radius $1$ (blue), with total volume $3\cdot2\pi=6\pi$
- Six $2×2×1$ cuboids (white) with total volume $24$
- a central cube (pink) of side $2$ which is $C$ and has volume $8$

[image]

Hence the total volume is $32+\frac{22}3\pi$.

Comment: Can you please explain it more that how we get these sub-structures?

Comment: @MittalG I added a Blender picture.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel kindly suggest some texts to tackle such probelms. Thanks.